# Is it possible to map all elements in the set of Natural numbers to the set of Rational numbers that is also one to one?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having difficulty trying to think of a bijective function that can map the set of natural numbers to the set of rational numbers. Is such a function even possible?

A function I thought up is f(x) : x/2
this function is injective but not surjective I believe?

Comment: Alternatively, speaking solely for functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$, you have, in essence, the Cantor pairing function ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function)), which can be visualized in a map to the positive rationals [as so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#/media/File:Diagonal_argument.svg). Adjusting as necessary to all rationals is trivial.

Comment: @PrincessEev is a mapping of rationals to naturals the same as a mapping of naturals to rationals?

Comment: They're not, but being a bijection they are necessarily invertible, so unless you really **must** go $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$, either direction will suffice for this purpose.

Comment: And yes, you are correct that $f(x)=x/2$ is not at all sufficient. It is injective, trivially, but definitely not surjective ($f(x)$ is never equal to $1/3$, for instance).

Comment: @PrincessEev I went through all the answers in the post you linked, and unfortunately i understood very little. Is there not a simple function to map the naturals to rationals?

Comment: Just because one exists need not mean a *simple* one exists. After all, you're dealing with the naturals (very "simple" objects) and the rationals (which are a lot more complicated, on top of having to deal with issues like the top and bottom being coprime to avoid double-counting, among others). I don't see a reason why a simple bijection should exist.

Comment: Arguably, the simplest such function is given by the Stern-Brocot tree, which is, er, well, go read and decide for yourself whether you'd call it simple.